# In software center, Error "apt transaction returned result exit failed" And getting following error. Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: apt, updates

```
W:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, those are mostly warnings with one error.

If you read them it tells you the problem:

```
E:Failed to fetch 
 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
 404 Not Found 
E:Some index files failed to download. 
  They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The maintainer of the PPA does not have a package for xenial.

Either

1. contact the maintainer - https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/next
2. Disable the PPA and find another source for the package(s) you want.

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak is dead. No updates since early 2015 therefore you're #1 is a waste of time.